# Landscape mode only when playing video. xcode. ios 7

Tags: xcode, video, ios7, youtube, landscape

I use youtube-ios-player-helper: https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper and https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper

I have everything working well. Video playback is fine!
BUT!
In the project settings, I turned off landscape mode.Therefore, the video only plays in portrait mode. How do I turn on landscape mode when playing video in iOS 7?

Comment: Did you already solve this issue? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My solution:**

*it works for iOS 7 and iOS 8*

To play a video from YouTube, I used XCDYouTubeKit (https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit)

*AppDelegate.h:*

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL screenIsPortraitOnly;
```

*AppDelegate.m:*

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{

    if (!self.screenIsPortraitOnly) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
    else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    }
}
```

*MYTableViewController.m:*

```
#import "XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController.h"
#import "XCDYouTubeKit.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController *videoPlayerViewController = [[XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController alloc] initWithVideoIdentifier:myIdYoutube];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:videoPlayerViewController  name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:videoPlayerViewController.moviePlayer];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(videoFinished) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:videoPlayerViewController.moviePlayer];
    videoPlayerViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
    [self presentViewController:videoPlayerViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)videoFinished
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    appDelegate.screenIsPortraitOnly = false;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

*XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController.m*

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

- (instancetype) initWithVideoIdentifier:(NSString *)videoIdentifier
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    appDelegate.screenIsPortraitOnly = true;
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] integerValue] >= 8)
        self = [super initWithContentURL:nil];
    else
        self = [super init];

    if (!self)
        return nil;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];

    if (videoIdentifier)
        self.videoIdentifier = videoIdentifier;

    return self;
}

- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    appDelegate.screenIsPortraitOnly = false;

    if (![self isBeingDismissed])
        return;

    [self.videoOperation cancel];
}
```